# How to check if the input box value has changed before it using knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

Here is my simple fiddle that i created. It uses knockout and created a simple input box and button

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smihit_123/h28cvev9/)

```
<form>
    <p>Login name:
        <input data-bind="textInput: userName" />
    </p>
    <button data-bind="click: Onclick">Save</button>
</form>

ko.applyBindings({
    userName: ko.observable("abcd"),
    Onclick: function () {
        // add an alert if value has changed or do nothing. 
        // tried adding the alert but it didnt fire with the value in the input box

    }
});
```

I was trying the scenario in knockout where if the value of input box hasn't changed then there is no effect on clicking save.

But if the value of the input box has changed then on clicking Save would perform an action say firing an alert box.

My questions mainly are :

1. How can i trace back the previous value of the input box before
   it gets updated.
2. I am doing this mainly to improve the efficiency
   in our system to not to make a round trip to the database if there
   are no changes

Any suggestions or help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knockout already does the change tracking, you only need to tap into it. Subscribe to the `userName` and set a `dirty` flag. Reset the flag after a successful server update, like this:

```
function ViewModel () {
    var self = this;

    // data
    self.userName = ko.observable("abcd");
    self.dirty = ko.observable(false);

    // subscriptions
    self.userName.subscribe(function () {
        self.dirty(true);
    });

    // API
    self.saveChanges = function () {
        if (!self.dirty()) return;

        $.post("url", {
            userName: self.userName()
        }).done(function () {
            self.dirty(false);
        });
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

now you can even bind the "enabled" state of the Save button to that flag.

```html
<form>
    <p>Login name: <input data-bind="textInput: userName" /></p>
    <button data-bind="click: saveChanges, enabled: dirty">Save</button>
</form>
```

---

**Important note** Due to the global nature of the `dirty` flag you should lock the view during the save process. Otherwise the user could in theory make additional changes, but the dirty flag gets reset when the `saveChanges` process for the *previous* state returns and the user effectively loses the ability to save their new changes.

You can do that with the help of an `updating` flag:

```
self.dirty = ko.observable(false);
self.updating = ko.observable(false);

self.saveChanges = function () {
    if (!self.dirty()) return;

    self.updating(true);
    $.post("url", {
        userName: self.userName()
    }).done(function () {
        self.dirty(false);
    }).always(function () {
        self.updating(false);
    });
});
```

You might want to use that flag to show a "saving..." overlay or simply use it as `data-bind="disabled: updating"` on every input element on your page.

---

If you have many properties in your model that would contribute to a `dirty` state and you don't want to pollute your view model with many subscriptions, you can use an extender for the job:

```
ko.extenders.dirtyTrack = function (target, dirtyObservable) {
    target.subscribe(function () {
        dirtyObservable(true);
    });
    return target;
};
```

and in your view

```
// data
self.dirty = ko.observable(false);
self.userName = ko.observable("abcd").extend({dirtyTrack: self.dirty});
self.oherField = ko.observable("foo").extend({dirtyTrack: self.dirty});
```

Comment: Thanks. awesome explanation. This code samples made it very clear to me